# What's the difference between phys_copy and memcpy in the Minix kernel?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, kernel, minix

What the difference between phys_copy and memcpy in Minix?

```
/*===========================================================================*/
/*              phys_copy                    */
/*===========================================================================*/
/*
 * PUBLIC phys_bytes phys_copy(phys_bytes source, phys_bytes destination,
 *          phys_bytes bytecount); 
 * Copy a block of data from anywhere to anywhere in physical memory.
 */
/*      es edi esi eip   src dst len */
ENTRY(phys_copy)
    push    %ebp
    mov %esp, %ebp

    cld
    push    %esi
    push    %edi

    mov 8(%ebp), %esi
    mov 12(%ebp), %edi
    mov 16(%ebp), %eax

    cmp $10, %eax   /* avoid align overhead for small counts */
    jb  pc_small
    mov %esi, %ecx  /* align source, hope target is too */
    neg %ecx
    and $3, %ecx    /* count for alignment */
    sub %ecx, %eax

    rep     movsb (%esi), (%edi)
    mov %eax, %ecx
    shr $2, %ecx    /* count of dwords */

    rep     movsl (%esi), (%edi)
    and $3, %eax
pc_small:
    xchg    %eax, %ecx  /* remainder */

    rep     movsb (%esi), (%edi)

    mov $0, %eax        /* 0 means: no fault */
LABEL(phys_copy_fault)      /* kernel can send us here */
    pop %edi
    pop %esi
    pop %ebp
    ret

LABEL(phys_copy_fault_in_kernel)    /* kernel can send us here */
    pop %edi
    pop %esi
    pop %ebp
    mov %cr2, %eax
    ret
```

https://github.com/Stichting-MINIX-Research-Foundation/minix/blob/4db99f4012570a577414fe2a43697b2f239b699e/minix/kernel/arch/i386/klib.S#L164

Comment: That is just a memcpy, from `ds:src` to `es:dst`.  The comment mentions ES, perhaps it's called with non-zero ES base?  But probably not, because the comment describes the source operand as `phys_bytes` as well, so a caller would have to have set DS and ES base.  (But perhaps not SS base?).  It does avoid using anything except `movsb` for  copying, even after ensuring the copy size is >= 10 bytes it uses `rep movsb` instead of a 4-byte copy that might partially overlap.  But that might just be an implementation choice or missed optimization.  (Or good optimization for possible page-splits)

Comment: Oh, probably having a special function for `phys_copy` means the page-fault handler can distinguish use-cases by the saved-EIP, so it only jumps to `phys_copy_fault` or `phys_copy_fault_in_kernel` from page faults that happened in it, not from faults in `memcpy` (assuming there is a separate `memcpy` in the Minix kernel?)  I assume Minix direct-maps some or all of physical memory so there are virtual addresses for every physical address.

Comment: @PeterCordes You can also see [in the arm version](https://github.com/Stichting-MINIX-Research-Foundation/minix/blob/4db99f4012570a577414fe2a43697b2f239b699e/minix/kernel/arch/earm/phys_copy.S#L83) that the same code is used for both `phys_copy` and `memcpy`. The only major difference is the fault handling.